# IgnoreDataMember attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have marked some property as IgnoreDataMember attribute in my model class but while JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) that propery get ignored so how can available that property property using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model) when marked as IgnoreDataMember.

Comment: What is your main reason to use `IgnoreDataMember` in your class?

Comment: don't want that property in xml when converting class to xml

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore property in xml and only serialize with Json, just use `[XmlIgnore]` attribute

Comment: I have tried using [XmlIgnore] but its not working still that property visible generated xml